# Anyone learned in sanskrit please translate this verse for me

Tags: scripture, bhagavata-purana, sanskrit, bhakti, translation

Śrimad Bhagavatam 8.16.21.:

> स विधास्यति ते कामान्हरिर्दीनानुकम्पन: ।
> अमोघा भगवद्भ‍क्तिर्नेतरेति मतिर्मम ॥ २१ ॥
>
> sa vidhāsyati te kāmān
> harir dīnānukampanaḥ
> amoghā bhagavad-bhaktir
> netareti matir mama

Does it mean we should not pray to any other god than Vishnu to alleivate our sufferings.?

Answer (score 2):

S.B. 8.16.21.:

> स विधास्यति ते कामान्हरिर्दीनानुकम्पन: ।
> अमोघा भगवद्भ‍क्तिर्नेतरेति मतिर्मम ॥ २१ ॥
>
> Hari, who is very merciful to the poor, will fulfill all of your desires, for devotional service unto Him is infallible. Any method other than devotional service is useless. That is my opinion.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..